# What does make distclean do?

Tags: compiling, make

I'm new to compilation. I'm installing [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and there's a `make distclean` (or once there was `make clean`) after every step. What does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally the files that can be cleaned are determined automatically by Automake. Of course, Automake also recognizes some variables that can be defined to specify additional files to clean. These variables are `MOSTLYCLEANFILES`, `CLEANFILES`, `DISTCLEANFILES`, and `MAINTAINERCLEANFILES`.

Editing your automake.am to specify what gets deleted.

If `configure` built it, then `distclean` should delete it.

[Source](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Clean)

Short answer
`make distclean` (does not work on ALL programs but most) will remove ALL files made by `./configure` and ALL files made by `make`

Answer (score 5):

According to [GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html),

> ‘distclean’
>
> Delete all files in the current directory (or created by this makefile) that are created by configuring or building the program. If you have unpacked the source and built the program without creating any other files, ‘make distclean’ should leave only the files that were in the distribution. However, there is no need to delete parent directories that were created with ‘mkdir -p’, since they could have existed anyway.

Comment: I just found private files I made in the directory remains but `'tags'` file that I generated by `ctags -R *` is also removed.